# error when using new google shopping api in magento 1.6.1

Tags: magento, google-shopping-api

I'm getting this error when trying to add products to google content, my google account seems ok the site is verified, I've mapped attributes , price, name , description , condition.

Any ideas ?

Error code: auth/frontend/whitelisted. Internal reason: Customer xxxxxx has not been whitelisted for the Content API for Shopping. See 'request' for product 'The Fairytale Forest Album' (in 'Default Store View' store)

Answer (score 0):

your account needs to be approved for access to the content API fill in this form and wait for google. http://support.google.com/merchants/bin/request.py?contact_type=content_api